# Dual booting win 10/ Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

So, I have made a USB drive with 15.10 version of Ubuntu using [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Now when I try to restart the computer with the USB stick in there but the computer doesn't start, when I take USB out, it boots up to win 10.

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you have secure boot on, it may prevent booting from anything else, since not secure. You probably have to turn on a setting to allow boot from external devices or turn off secure boot. Also in Windows make sure fast startup is off. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and:http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 go to the start button which looks like this 
[image]

and then while clicking on the Shutdown(Restart) also press SHIFT key then follow the on screen instructions to boot via UEFI USB device. Now at the restart the computer will boot from the USB stick.

Comment: So, it worked and i could choose the USB drive, but nothing happened  and just started win 10 again.

Comment: Please check the boot order in BIOS. Also disable secure boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

At boot (before windows starts) press F1, enter bios.

Find Secure Boot and disable it.

Change boot order to USBkey on the top. (Or press F12 at boot)

If the problem persists , change boot order to Lagacy First, then UEFI.